# Magento 2 Footer does not update

Tags: blocks, footer-links

I am working on a problem with updating the content of the footer in Magento (Adobe Commerce ver. 2.4.5-p1). I am rather new to working with Magento and appreciate any help.

A few days ago, my colleague updated the markup for a few blocks via the Magento admin area. In our case, we have a simple list in the block that will be displayed in the footer. However, the most recently added list entry "Compliance" is still missing.

We tried flushing the Magento Cache, and double-checked that the store view selected for the block is the same that we are looking at in the front-end.

This is the markup for our block:

```
<div class="title"><span>Service & Support</span></div><ul>
<li><a href="{{store url=""}}kundenservice/zertifikate.html" target="_self">Zertifikate</a></li>
<li><a href="{{store url=""}}kundenservice/training.html" target="_self">Training</a></li>
<li><a href="{{store url=""}}service/produktfinder.html" target="_self">ProduktFinder</a></li>
<li><a href="{{store url=""}}kundenservice/versand.html" target="_self">Versand und Lieferung</a></li>
<li><a href="{{store url=""}}service/compliance.html" target="_self">Compliance</a></li>    
    <li><a href="{{store url=""}}kundenservice/faqs-eshop.html" target="_self">eshop FAQ</a></li>
<li><a href="{{store url=""}}kundenservice/eprocurement.html" target="_self">eProcurement</a></li></ul>
```

Is there anything we are missing, either with the code itself or the way to get it working?

Comment: remove pub/static and run php bin/magento static:scontent:deploy -f

Comment: Inspect the footer block in the front-end and check if there are any CSS issues that are hiding the "Compliance" list entry